# How to use ** for exponents using @infix func **( )?

Tags: swift, operators, infix-operator

I want to use `**` to overload an exponent function. I works if I use something like "^" but the python way of doing is `**` and I would like to use that with Swift. Any way to do that?

> error: Operator implementation without matching operator declaration

```
@infix func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{
    return pow(num, power)
}

println(8.0**3.0) // Does not work
```

Comment: Are you sure `^` works as intended? I've only got it to act as an addition: `println(1^2) == 3`

Comment: @vol7ron `^` is the Bitwise XOR Operator. `1^2` is just coincidentally equal to `1+2`. Please see [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language), Language Guide -> Advanced Operators -> Bitwise XOR Operator.

Comment: @Lensflare: I was speaking of Python, where `^` does not act as an exponent.  I think I was wrong and misread the question, which suggests that he could overload `^` in Swift to act as a caret, but he wanted to use `**`, which was not working when trying to overload.

Comment: You need to use Jamie's answer to tell the compiler what function name you want to use.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to declare the operator before defining the function, as follows:

In Swift 2:

```
import Darwin

infix operator ** {}

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(num, power)
}

println(8.0 ** 3.0) // works
```

In Swift 3:

```
import Darwin

infix operator **

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(num, power)
}

print(8.0 ** 3.0) // works
```

Comment: As of beta 6 it must be written `infix operator ** {}`.

Comment: Thanks @Klaas, I updated the answer for Xcode 6 beta 6.

Comment: Swift3: ``infix operator **`` <--curly braces not needed

Comment: Thanks @GitSyncApp, I updated the answer with Swift 3 code as well.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that ** is executed before neighboring * or /, you'd better set a precedence.

```
infix operator ** { associativity left precedence 160 }
```

As http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/ shows, the exponentiative operators have 160 precedence, like << and >> bitwise shift operators do.